# Stringify does not stringify the virtual populated object

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, ejs

**This is my object which is passed to view:**

```
app.get('/view_add_requests', isLoggedIn, function (req, res) {
     var my_id = req.user._id;  // this is the senders id & id of logged in user


     FriendReq.find({to_id: my_id}).populate('profile').exec( function (err, result) {
             if(err) res.send(err);

             res.render('view_add_requests', { result : result });
     });
})
```

**On <% result %> in view it prints**

```
{ _id: 59625cbb2e9f1b7cdc968666, from_id: '59625cb52e9f1b7cdc968664', to_id: '59625caf2e9f1b7cdc968662', msg: 'Hi ! I would like to be your friend!', __v: 0, profile2: null, profile: [ { _id: 59625cb52e9f1b7cdc968665, about: 'null', status: 'Happy', picture: 'https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p200x200/17361955_10208706527529679_1126407854127685629_n.jpg?oh=a4fc39a10fed1abf09bf526046aaa671&oe=5A038BFC', work: 'Duopod Design Limited', language: 'Hindi', relationship_status: 'Single', interested_in: 'female', location: 'Auckland, New Zealand', birthday: '03/28/1993', gender: 'male', name: 'Andy Karwal', id: '10209588148249646', __v: 0, user_id: [Object] } ], id: '59625cbb2e9f1b7cdc968666' }
```

**in my route for console.log(result) it prints:**

```
[ { _id: 59625cbb2e9f1b7cdc968666,
from_id: '59625cb52e9f1b7cdc968664',
to_id: '59625caf2e9f1b7cdc968662',
msg: 'Hi ! I would like to be your friend!',
__v: 0,
profile2: null,
profile: [ [Object] ],
id: '59625cbb2e9f1b7cdc968666' } ]
```

while

```
<%= JSON.stringify(result) %>
```

prints

```
[{"_id":"59625cbb2e9f1b7cdc968666","from_id":"59625cb52e9f1b7cdc968664","to_id":"59625caf2e9f1b7cdc968662","msg":"Hi ! I would like to be your friend!","__v":0}]
```

Stringify seems to ignore the nested Object. How do i access it in view?
JSON.parse(result) returns an `**error: unexpected token _ in JSON at position 2**`
ive tried:

```
<%- result._id %> <%- result.profile[0].name %> <%- result["_id"] %>
```

All return undefined. How do i access the virtual populated fields in "profile" i.e name, picture etc. ? Please guide.

Comment: `JSON.stringify()` only includes enumerable properties that are not functions.  I'd suggest checking the enumerability of the property in question.  And, wat are "virtual populated fields"?  Can you describe them in terms of actual Javascript terms and definitions?

Comment: I figured it out. I was not considering the parent array >> <%- result[0].profile[0].name %>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this with `<%- result[0].profile[0].name %>`